# Sort a COUNTIF function based on a list from the UNIQUE function in Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have a list of events which includes the US state in which they occurred. I used the `UNIQUE()` function.

[[image]

to create a summary table, and the COUNTIF function to count occurrences.

[image]

I would like a formula to sort by the largest number of occurrences (i.e. MN would be second in the list in the image, followed by NE, and so on...)

This list of events is being added to daily, so I would like to find a formula to automatically sort the summary list rather than using a filter. I have tried `=SORT(UNIQUE)`, (and admittedly I do not entirely understand all the uses of the SORT function) but I am looking to sort by count, not alphabetically.

Comment: First convert the range into a `Structured References` i.e. `Tables` and then use a formula like: `=LET(x, Table1, y, UNIQUE(x), SORT(HSTACK(y,COUNTIFS(x,y)),2,-1))` where `Table1` is the data with `US` States abbreviations. Also it seems like from the screenshots you are using `Google Sheets` then the formula may be different which i am not sure abt. or may work as well. To know more on `SORT()` function please do read `MSFT` documentation that might help **[MSFT_Doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c)**

Comment: Or, more simple way is using `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()` those are presently available in `MS365` Beta users, : `=GROUPBY(Table1,Table1,COUNTA,0,0,-2)` that last `-2` refers to the column index and the sorting order.

Comment: are you using Google Sheets? The screenshots don't look like Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to work on this, but in terms of readability maybe use `GROUPBY()`:

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(Table1,Table1,COUNTA,0,0,-2)
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(x, Table1, y, UNIQUE(x), SORT(HSTACK(y,COUNTIFS(x,y)),2,-1))
```

---

**Note:** `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()` functions are presently available in `MS365` Beta Versions. Also ensure to convert the range into a `Structured References` aka `Tables` that helps in automatically adjust thus minimizing the need to update the ranges manually in the formulas, as well as ensures to save time, with less risk of errors.

One more thing, which i have realized from the screenshots you have posted in the OP, it seems like you are using `Google Sheets` which I have commented above, the above formulas may need some changes. Shown below.

---

• In `Google-Sheets`

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, TOCOL(G2:G,1), y, UNIQUE(x), SORT(HSTACK(y,COUNTIFS(x,y)),2,FALSE))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Sheets, you can use the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=QUERY(G2:G,"select Col1, count(Col1)
             where Col1 is not null
             group by Col1
             order by count(Col1) desc
             label Col1 'State List', count(Col1) 'Count'")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
=LET(a,A1:A9,U, UNIQUE(a),S,SORTBY(U,MAP(U, LAMBDA(x, COUNTIF(a,x))),-1), HSTACK(S,SORT(MAP(U, LAMBDA(x, COUNTIF(a,x))),,-1)))
```

Replace `A1:A9` with your range.

You'll need Microsoft Office 365 for this to work.

[image: Excel]

Answer (score 0):

### `CountIf` Sorted

In `L2`:

```
=LET(data,G2:G2000,
    u,UNIQUE(TOCOL(data,1)),
    c,COUNTIF(data,u),
SORT(HSTACK(u,c),2,-1))
```

[image]